# Being paid in Bitcoin from another country

Tags: transactions

If I sold property in another country, could I be paid in bitcoin in a basic wallet to wallet transaction if the value is 500k+?

Comment: People voting to close this as "cryptocurrencies or projects that are not Bitcoin", why? The question is literally about bitcoin. It may be warranted to close this as offtopic due to being too dependent on jurisdiction, this site not being for legal advice, or lacking details.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, as long as it's a legal transaction in your country.

Comment: Even if it isn't legal, the bitcoin transaction will still go through (though obviously you may encounter other troubles, from local law enforcement or whatever).

Comment: True. I assumed it was more of a "am I practically able to" and in that case if the payment isn't legally accepted, OP may run into problems getting the title to the property transferred or other such legal steps.